# Can I get the browser width and height in Pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid

Is it possible to get the user's browser width and height in Pyramid? I've searched through the response object and Googled.

If it's not available in Pyramid, I'll just grab it in javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that is not possible to determine with server-side code only. Browsers do not share that information when making HTTP requests to the server.

You'll have to do this with JavaScript.